# Jquery change image url to class within the same div

Tags: jquery

This is my situtation:

```
<div>
 <p class:"test">text1</p>
 <img src="" class="image">
</div>

<div>
 <p class:"test">text2</p>
 <img src="" class="image">
</div>
```

I want to replace the (src) value for each of the images to the text of the class(test) that is in the same div as it.
I want be outcome to be the following code sample:

```
      <div>
 <p class:"test">text1</p>
 <img src="text1" class="image">
</div>

<div>
 <p class:"test">text2</p>
 <img src="text2" class="image">
</div>
```

Updated:

```
This is my code:
$(".poster div").each(function() { 
    var txt = $(this).find("a").parent("h4").text();
    $(this).find(".avatar img").parent("a").parent(".avatar li").attr("src", txt);
});
```

but it doesn't work
This is what I want it to work on:

```
<div class="poster">
 <h4>
  <a>name</a>
 </h4>
 <li class="avatar">
  <a>
   <img src="" class="avatar">
  </a>
 </li>
</div>
```

and I want the outcome to be:

```
<div class="poster">
 <h4>
  <a>name</a>
 </h4>
 <li class="avatar">
  <a>
   <img src="name" class="avatar">
  </a>
 </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace the values on what event? What triggers the change of values?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Patel, it triggers when the website it loaded

Comment: You should really go look at the jquery api docs for parent - http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".poster").each(function() { 
    var txt = $(this).find("h4 a").text().trim();
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", txt);
});
```

Comment: I used your code but I have problems implementing it. I updated my question with a more accurate situation. I'm wondering if you can help alter the code to work the way I want, thx

Comment: your selector - $(".poster div") is wrong. it should be $("div.poster").

I also don't know why you have so many $.parent traversals, but...see my updated answer.

Comment: works, only I get this in between the src"" _ = [space]
"__________________________________________________________
________________________________name______________________
_______________________________"

Comment: should be $(this).find("h4 a").text()

Comment: omg, thx! it worked :D
I'm unable to press the up arrow though. It says I need 15 rep

Comment: Is there a way to make this work the same but only target images with a certain width

Answer (score 0):

You can select the previous elements text attribute and assign it to the image src attribute like so

```js
$(function () {
    $('img').each(function () {
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).prev().text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <p class="test">text1</p>
 <img src="" class="image">
</div>

<div>
 <p class="test">text2</p>
 <img src="" class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know about .each()

Comment: Wait, is there a missing ")" on the second line?

Comment: Nope, no missing parenthesis